# RPN calculator c++ error handling and multiple operators

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack, calculator, rpn

Edit::
I've made changes to my program. Take a look at calc.cpp. In particular, the isOperator function, and the fourth while loop-- that is

```
while (isOperator(std::cin.peek()))
...
   ...
   if ( op == '/')
```

I believe the problem is that char op isn't being set to '/'. When I go back into my isOperator function

```
int isOperator(char ch)
{
   int count = 0;
   char ops[] = {'-','+','*','/', '^'};
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {   
       if (ch == ops[i])
          count++;
   }
   return count;
}
```

and change

```
char ops[] = {'^','-','+','*','/'};
```

to

```
char ops[] = {'-','+','*','/', '^'};
```

op can be set to '/', but not '^'.  There must be something simple I'm not seeing.

Dstack.h (stack class):

```
#ifndef DSTACK_H
#define DSTACK_H

#include <iostream>

class Dstack
{
   public:
      Dstack();
      ~Dstack();
      void push(double value);
      bool pop(double &value);
      double top();
      int size();
      bool empty();
      bool print();
  private:
      class Node
      {
         public:
            Node(double value, Node* next)
            {m_value = value; m_next = next;}
            double m_value;
            Node* m_next;
     };
     Node* m_head;
 };


#endif
```

Dstack.cpp (stack function definitions):

```
#include "dstack.h"
#include <iostream>

Dstack::Dstack()
{
   m_head = NULL;
}

void Dstack::push(double value)
{
   m_head = new Node (value, m_head);
}

bool Dstack::pop(double &value)
{
   if (m_head == NULL)
   return false;

   value = m_head->m_value;
   Node *temp = m_head;
   m_head = m_head->m_next;
   delete temp;
   return true;
}

double Dstack::top()
{
   double value = m_head->m_value;
   return value;
}         

int Dstack::size()
{
  int count = 0;
  Node *ptr = m_head;
  while (ptr != NULL)
  {
     count++; 
     ptr = ptr->m_next;
  }
  return count;
}   

bool Dstack::empty()
{
   if (m_head == NULL)
   return true;

   return false;
}

Dstack::~Dstack()
{
   Node* ptr = m_head;
   while (ptr != NULL)
   {
      Node* temp = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->m_next;
      delete temp;
   } 
}

bool Dstack::print()
{
   //if (m_head->m_next == NULL)
   //return false;

   std::cout << m_head->m_value << std::endl;
   return true;
}
```

Calc.cpp (calculator functions)

```
#include "dstack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream> 

int isOperator(char ch) 
{ 
   int count = 0;  
   char ops[] = {'-','+','*','^','/'};
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
   {   
      if (ch == ops[i])
      count++;
   }   
   return count;
}


int main()
{ 
   Dstack stack;
   double num;
   double result = 0;
   char op = '\0';
   double a = 0;
   double b = 0;


   while (std::cin.peek() != EOF)
   {   
      std::cin >> std::ws;
      while (isdigit(std::cin.peek()))
      {     
         std::cin >> num;
         stack.push(num);

         while(isspace (std::cin.peek()))
         {   
            std::cin.ignore();
            std::cin.peek();
         }   
     }   

     while (isOperator(std::cin.peek())) 
     {

        //make sure there is more than one operand to calculate
        if (stack.size() <2)
        {
           std::cerr << "Error: Invalid Expression." << std::endl;
           exit(1);
        }

        //make sure there are enough operators
        if (isOperator(std::cin.peek() +1 < stack.size() ))
        {
           std::cerr << "Error: Invalid Expression." << std::endl;
           exit(1);
        }

        //clear white space for each cycle
        std::cin >> std::ws; 

        //operate!
        std::cin >> op;
        if (op == '+')
        {

           b = stack.top();
           stack.pop(b);
           a = stack.top();
           stack.pop(a);
           result = a + b;
           stack.push(result);
       }
       if (op == '-')
       {
           b = stack.top();
           stack.pop(b);
           a = stack.top();
           stack.pop(a);
           result = a - b;
           stack.push(result);
       }
       if (op == '*')
       {
           b = stack.top();
           stack.pop(b);
           a = stack.top();
           stack.pop(a);
           result = a * b;
           stack.push(result);
       }
        if (op == '^')
       {
          b = stack.top();
          stack.pop(b);
          a = stack.top();
          stack.pop(a);

          result = pow(a,b);
          stack.push(result);
      }
       if (op == '/')
        {
           b = stack.top();
           stack.pop(b);
           a = stack.top();
           stack.pop(a);

           //b cant equal 0!!!
           if (b == 0)
           {
              std::cerr << "Error: Invalid expression." << std::endl;
              exit(1);
           }
           result = a / b;
           stack.push(result);
        }

        std::cout << op << std::endl;

        //move char to next position    
        std::cin.peek();

        //ignore possible white spaces left in expression and repeat
        while (isspace (std::cin.peek()))
        {
           std::cin.ignore();
           std::cin.peek();
        }
     }
}
   if (stack.size() == 1)
      std::cout << result << std::endl;
   else
   {
      std::cerr << "Error: Invalid expression." << std::endl;
      exit(1);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, that's not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and I also recommend [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for  informing me about proper examples. I've been plugging away and have a more specific question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, I would recommend a total refactoring of your input handling.

First of all to [read whole lines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and then to parse the input line *character by character*. That way it's actually easier to recognize and handle operators of all kinds.

For example: Get the next character from the input line, and check what type of character it is:

- For [white-space](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), just discard the character and continue with the next
- If it's a [digit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), fetch characters while it's a digit and construct the number from that
- If it's a valid operator then handle it
- If it's something else then handle the error (for example by skipping the current line and read the next)

As you can see a kind of error handling of input is kind of built-in into the method described above.

It's also easy to expand the above to recognize *symbols*, that can be used for variables or functions.

---

The main loops could look something like this in code:

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    for (size_t current_char_index = 0; current_char_index < line-size(); ++current_char_index)
    {
        // TODO: Handle current character at line[current_char_index]
    }
}
```

For practicality I also suggest splitting main code into functions.

Lastly, and unless your exercise is about making your own stack class, use [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).